"@id" in schema.org
Schema.org says:

All syntaxes have built in identifier" for example in json-ld we have: @id

Can I use @id to mention to sections in my page?
My page have 3 section with 3 id. Can I use @id as selector to my page or it should refer to official contents?
<div id="i"></div>

    
"@type": "Product",
"@id": "https://example.com/item#i"

